# Sqlbuddy login not working with PHP 7.0

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, sqlbuddy

I have searched for an answer to this, but haven't found anything.  I was wondering if anyone had come across the same issue and had any insight.  I have PHP 7.0 installed on an nginx web server with [sqlbuddy](http://sqlbuddy.com/).  When attempting to login to the homepage `http://localhost/sqlbuddy/`, I receive an HTTP 500 error (Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Edge tested). PHP 7.0 is installed with the following packages:

- php-apcu
- php-cli
- php-common
- php-curl
- php-fpm
- php-gd
- php-json
- php-mbstring
- php-mcrypt
- php-memcache
- php-mysql
- php7.0-cgi
- php7.0-cli
- php7.0-common
- php7.0-curl
- php7.0-fpm
- php7.0-gd
- php7.0-json
- php7.0-mbstring
- php7.0-mcrypt
- php7.0-mysql
- php7.0-opcache
- php7.0-readline
- php7.0-xml

Installation of [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) on the web server works fine, along with a test page containing a PDO connection setup similar to the one found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp).

Comment: It's because sqlbuddy uses mysql_connect() which was deprecated in php5. I don't know how to fix the problem.

Comment: Late reply, but this guy did replace all mysql_ references to mysqli.
https://github.com/Frecuencio/sqlbuddy-php7

which makes sqlbuddy up n running on PHP7.
I'm in the process to revamp this project
https://github.com/remi-grumeau/sqlbuddy-php7/tree/v2

Answer (score 0):

the error is 
`PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()`

If you using with PHP V7.0 you should try this repo

https://github.com/Frecuencio/sqlbuddy-php7

====[EDIT]====

the problem is because you don't allow log errors for php, try to allow log errors on the nginx server

if you have an error log for php, then when you go to http://localhost/sqlbuddy you will get this error:

`PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect ()`

the mysql_connect() function is only applies to php5 - php4.
in this case your using with php7, and you must try that package.

*sorry for bad explanation i hope you will understand

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. FYI, you should avoid answers like "please try..." without explanation. E.g. you could write, why this error occures (mysql removement in php 7.0). Nothing personal.